# How to process JSON

Tags: json, go, struct

I'm building a web server with Go and I don't know how to process JSON with Go.

Saying that I have a struct as below:

```
type User struct{
    Id int
    Name string
    Password string
    Status int
}
```

and now I have had an object of the struct User:

```
user := User{1, "Test", "password", 1}
```

Now I need to convert `user` to a JSON object. Here is what I've found:

```
b, err := json.Marshal(user)
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

It works well.
Now I want to do two things:
1) remove the `Password` from the JSON object
2) add a new filed: `"code": 200` into the JSON object

What should I do?

Comment: In addition to the answers consider something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/C0vEfs03VO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make `Password` lower case (and add `Code     int` to your struct):
Try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/88i-m9Mmtt):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    user := User{1, "Test", "password", 1, 200}
    b, err := json.Marshal(user)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

type User struct {
    Id       int
    Name     string
    password string
    Status   int
    Code     int
}
```

output:

```
{"Id":1,"Name":"Test","Status":1,"Code":200}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the `Password` property accessible to outer packages, you can set a tag: `json:"-"` on it. As specified in the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal):

> **The encoding of each struct field can be customized by the format
>   string stored under the "json" key in the struct field's tag**. The
>   format string gives the name of the field, possibly followed by a
>   comma-separated list of options. The name may be empty in order to
>   specify options without overriding the default field name.
>
> The "omitempty" option specifies that the field should be omitted from
>   the encoding if the field has an empty value, defined as false, 0, a
>   nil pointer, a nil interface value, and any empty array, slice, map,
>   or string.
>
> As a special case, **if the field tag is "-", the field is always
>   omitted**. Note that a field with name "-" can still be generated using
>   the tag "-,".

```
type User struct {
    Id       int
    Name     string
    Password string `json:"-"`
    Status   int
    Code     int `json:"code"`
}
```